Azure Function to generate PDF from HTML via Logic Apps
Salutations, Coding Gurus
I am looking for help with an azure function that can generate a pdf file from CSS formatted html triggered through a logic app.
The solution has to use an open source pdf library, possibly something like Puppeteer, wkhtmltopdf or jsPDF maybe?
And must handle complex html tables with dynamic data and critical formatting (like elegant page breaks within long tables etc.)
Grateful for any and all help on this…
Thanks in advance!

Provide the actions or flow of your logic app

It’s a simple http trigger that pulls the html out of a SharePoint list multi-line text field, from there I want to call an azure function that takes the html as the input and generates the pdf file (blob etc) returning the result to Logic Apps so I can use graph api and put the pdf file into a SharePoint Document Library

Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78076584/how-to-use-wkhtmltopdf-and-azure-functions-python-v2-together-to-convert-html-to/78080366#78080366?

You do not need to use Azure Functions to change to pdf from html, you can use connectors(many are there which converts html to pdf) in Logic apps like below:

If you want to use Azure functions you can use below code and containerize the function app and I followed my answer in SO-Thread:
import subprocess
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    cho_value = req.get_body().decode('utf-8')
    cho_htmlPath =r'C:\Users\bojja\Downloads\78282689.html'
    cho_outputFile = r'c:\Users\bojja\Downloads'
    with open(cho_htmlPath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as k:
        k.write(cho_value)
    subprocess.run(['c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe', cho_htmlPath, cho_outputFile])
    with open(cho_outputFile, 'rb') as resultfile:
        rescon = resultfile.read()
    return func.HttpResponse(rescon, mimetype='application/pdf', status_code=200)

And then you can call a function app from Logic app using below action:


Thanks for taking the time to respond @RithwikBojja I will go down this rabbit hole and see if I can make any progress... My requirement for this project is to not use 3rd party connectors so creating an azure function was my next best option.
